# Size of a partition or RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

How can we calculate the size of a partition in a RDD? Is it not a recommended to calculate the partition size ? I want to dynamically set the number of shuffle partition before I call any action, hence need to calculate the partition size and depending on the number of executors want to set the shuffle partition count.

Answer (score 1):

"I want to dynamically set the number of shuffle partition before I call any action"

unfortunately that's challenging todo in spark without diving deep into the low level code.  In fact this is something that adaptive execution in spark 3.0 is bringing to the table.  What it will do is over partition the dataset and then dynamically combine small partitions to reach a certain threshold.

https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/29/adaptive-query-execution-speeding-up-spark-sql-at-runtime.html

Answer (score -1):

you can get the RDD partition size using below command:
someRDD.partitions.size
you can use different methods of partitioning like:

1. based on the columns
2. based on the (ataset size)/(block size)
3. based on the cores available

Comment: someRDD.partitions.size will give me the number of partitions not the size of each partition in bytes.